# $n$ divides $\varphi(p^n-1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, field-theory, galois-theory

> Prove that $n$ divides $\varphi(p^n-1)$.

I want to check if my proof is correct.

Proof. $\text{Gal}(\Bbb F_{p^n}/\Bbb F_p)$ is a cyclic group of order $n$ and $|\text{Aut}(\Bbb F_{p^n}^\times)| = \varphi(p^n-1)$. For each automorphism $\Bbb F_{p^n}^\times\to\Bbb F_{p^n}^\times$, we extend it to $\Bbb F_{p^n}\to\Bbb F_{p^n}$ by defining $0\mapsto 0$. Then $\text{Gal}(\Bbb F_{p^n}/\Bbb F_p)<\text{Aut}(\Bbb F_{p^n})$ so that $n\mid\varphi(p^n-1)$.

Is the extension make sense?

Comment: Your proof is correct. But it is, perhaps, unnecessarily high browed in the sense that we can do with theory simpler than the Galois theory of finite fields :-)

Comment: I think that you might actually add your argument as an answer to the latter duplicate target!

Comment: A remark on your logic. I think that it may be better to **restrict** field automorphisms to the multiplicative subgroup rather than **extend** automorphisms of the multiplicative group. That shows that the Galois group is a subgroup of the automorphism group of the cyclic multiplicative group, when Lagrange gives the desired conclusion. The reason for me having second thoughts is that when $\mathrm{Aut}(\Bbb{F}_{p^n})$ is mentioned, I would be inclined to assume that automorphisms of the *additive group* are intended rather than those of the *multiplicative monoid*.